# django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker and Dango 1.11

Tags: django, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Nkunihiko [django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) looks abandoned and doesn't support for Django 1.11

I see a lot of pull requests to Nkunihiko repo, but they don't help.

Is there a current fork or some another django package for `bootstrap-datetimepicker`?

Answer (score 0):

though I don't use Django, you currently have the options to use the pull request [#65](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker/pull/65) or [#66](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker/pull/66) as some user did for [his project](https://github.com/mimischi/django-clock/pull/356) and seems to work.

> Is there a current fork or some another django package for bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Yes, currently [tutorchruncer/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) and [seems to work for Django 1.11](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker/pull/12)